# Fish command substitution doesn't work like in bash or zsh

Tags: fish

I have stumbled on a problem with the fish shell (which is my favorite shell) when I am trying to use command substitution:

```
gcc (pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 cairo) -o drawing_widget drawing_widget.c 
gcc: erreur: unrecognized command line option ‘-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
-I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 
-I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz 
-I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lcairo ’
```

I have tested with both bash and zsh and the equivalent comment works:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 cairo) -o drawing_widget drawing_widget.c
```

Comment: fish is treating the results of pkg-config as a single argument. You may need `eval`

Comment: I have read the doc and tried to use eval but I was not able to make it works  with "gcc (eval pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 cairo) -o drawing_widget drawing_widget.c"  or "set a pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 cairo" then gcc (eval $a) -o drawing_widget drawing_widget.c" for exemple

Comment: No, I was thinking `eval gcc (pkg-config ...) ...`

Comment: Sorry I can really be stupid sometimes. Your solution works too thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant difference is called "word splitting," which is how the result of a variable expansion or command substitution is turned into multiple arguments.

In bash and zsh, word splitting occurs on all whitespace. Example:

```
> for i in $(echo 1 2 3) ; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

In fish, word splitting occurs only on newlines:

```
> for i in (echo 1 2 3); echo $i; end
1 2 3
```

In the above, the loop only runs once, with $i set to '1 2 3'. The advantage of the fish behavior is that filenames with spaces, etc. don't cause problems like they do in bash.

`pkg-config` outputs space-separated text:

```
> pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl libssl
-lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz
```

So it's relying on bash's word splitting behavior. (But you'd be in trouble if any flags needed embedded whitespace.)

To get the same effect in fish, you can replace spaces with newlines. `tr` is a good tool for that:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl libssl | tr -s ' ' \n
```

The `-s` flag effectively cleans up a trailing space that pig-config outputs.

Comment: That was not obvious but it works thank you for the answer and for fish !

Answer (score 1):

To achieve word splitting, you can also use `fish`’s internal `string split` command:

```bash
pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl libssl | string split -n ' '
```

The `-n` or `--no-empty` option excludes empty results, such as consecutive spaces. The `' '` indicates the separator.

Thus, the complete command would be

```bash
gcc (pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 cairo | string split -n ' ') -o drawing_widget drawing_widget.c
```

[Using `eval` is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168110/2757533), because it will expand everything, even, say, the characters `*`, `$`, or `()`. Thus, it is entirely possible for `eval` to produce unintended output, and at worst, a maliciously crafted path name could be used to cause damage.