# fish shell pass argument from command

Tags: docker, fish

I'm trying to use fish with [docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) with docker client in fish shell. I can run `docker-machine config dev` and it would give me the parameters to pass to `docker`. But when I tried to do that `docker (docker-machine config dev) ps` it would say `flag provided but not defined: --tls --tlscacert`

If I switch my shell to bash then `docker $(docker-machine config dev) ps` works fine. So what's wrong with the syntax here?

I tried googling for the answer, seems like that error is related to Go, maybe?

Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef

fish, version 2.1.1

**EDIT:** Here is the output of `docker-machine config dev`

`--tls --tlscacert=/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/dev/ca.pem --tlscert=/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/dev/cert.pem --tlskey=/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/dev/key.pem -H="tcp://192.168.99.102:2376"`

Comment: could you include your docker versions.

Comment: You probably have an old version of docker in your fish shell's path. Compare the environment between your 2 shells, and/or run `docker version` in each.

Comment: Running docker 1.5.0

Comment: I think that the result of `(docker-machine config dev)` cannot be parsed by fish. Can you run `docker-machine config dev` and paste the result in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128669/fish-command-substitution-doesnt-work-like-in-bash-or-zsh/28129450?noredirect=1#comment44631961_28129450).

The short answer is that bash will further split command substitutions into separate arguments on any whitespace, while fish splits them only with newlines. Since `docker-machine config dev` doesn't output newlines, the outer `docker` command just gets one giant argument, with embedded spaces.

To simulate the bash behavior, you can replace spaces with newlines:

```
docker (docker-machine config dev | tr -s ' ' \n) ps
```

That should do what you expect.

Comment: Would be nice to know how this is done in 2018... because I can't use docker in fish, but in bash it works